# 「５しゅうかん　日本語　を　べんきょうしました」or 「日本語　を　５しゅうかん　べんきょうしました」

Tags: word-order

> わたしは　くにで　５しゅうかん　日本語　を　べんきょうしました。
>
> わたしは　くにで　日本語　を　５しゅうかん　べんきょうしました。

I have seen sentence in this two orders. Which is more appropriate?

Comment: Just saying 国で sounds like 'I studied Japanese in a country.'

Comment: ^ そうでしょうか。「くにで～～べんきょうしました。」と聞くと、ふつうは「故郷で」"in my home country" という意味だと思うと思いますが。["4 生まれ育った土地。郷里。故郷。「盆と正月には国へ帰る」「国は富山です」"](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/62449/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AB/)のように。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my personal experience,

I would say that it depends on the circumstance...
It's probably pretty rare in daily life that that much specific information would ever occur in one sentence.

Usually there would be more than enough context to be able to avoid saying

1. **what you did** （study Japanese）,
2. **where you did it** (in your home country) and
3. **for how long** (5 weeks) and then
4. **emphasizing that it was you** （わたしは）

   all in one utterance.

Here's an example of where it might happen though...

The teacher says:

```
[皆]{みな}さんバケーションをどのように[過]{す}ごしましたか？ボブは？
 - How did you all spend your vacations? How about you Bob?
```

Bob says:

```
あっ、えぇと．．．[九州]{きゅうしゅう}へ[行]{い}ってボランティアしました。
 - Ummm, I went to Kyushu and did some volunteer work.
```

Then Sue says:

```
あたしは[香港]{ほんこん}で[買]{か}い[物]{もの}してた！[広東語]{かんとんご}もちょっと[勉強]{べんきょう}しました。
- I went shopping in Hong Kong! And I studied a little bit of Cantonese.
```

You might say:

> [僕]{ぼく}は[故郷]{ふるさと}に[帰]{かえ}って日本語を**３[週間]{しゅうかん}**[勉強]{べんきょう}していました。
>
> - I went back home and studied Japanese **for 3 weeks**.

OR

> 僕は[故郷]{ふるさと}に帰って**３週間**日本語を勉強していました。
>
> - I went back home and **for 3 weeks** I studied Japanese .

This one sounds a little repetitive in English, just because we have to repeat "I"... Doesn't sound that way in Japanese.

OR

> 僕は**３週間**[故郷]{ふるさと}に帰って日本語を勉強していました。
>
> - I went back home **for 3 weeks** and studied Japanese.

OR

> **３週間**僕は[故郷]{ふるさと}に帰って日本語を勉強していました。
>
> - **For 3 weeks** I went back home and studied Japanese.

This last one sounds like your over-emphasizing the fact that you were there for 3 whole weeks, so it would be a little out of place in this context.

Long story short, 3週間**日本語**を勉強しました and 日本語を**3週間**勉強しました, are grammatically equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the edit chocolate! How do you insert furigana like that?

Comment: @sazarando [漢字]のあとに {ふりがな} 、　または、漢字のあとに 「【ふりがな】」(←外側のかっこは要りません) とするとよいそうです。ここにいろいろ載ってました。http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se

Answer (score 3):

Both are same, you can choose as you like.

Answer (score 2):

They're pretty similar; no one would bat an eye if you swapped them most of the time. However there is a slight difference in that there's an implied emphasis or contrast on the beginning of a sentence. So you'd be more likely to use the first in talking about what you did at different times: For five weeks, I studied Japanese [and then...] vs. maybe using the second to contrast with a different language: I studied Japanese for five weeks [but my Spanish is better.]

Also, yeah, the sentences as you abbreviated then for your question title are much more conversational than the full text, but that's also not something you really need to worry about as a beginner.